# mysql, get last artikel in last kategori

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to take all the articles with 'IDJurnal' last of the database
this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `artikel`(
`IDArtikel` INT(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IDJurnal` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`IDKategori` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`judul` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`abstract` text NOT NULL,
`nama_file` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`hits` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`didownload` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`created_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`created_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`updated_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`IDArtikel`))ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 12 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

and my jurnal table is

```
CREATE TABLE `jurnal`(
`IDJurnal` INT(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`volume` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`nomor` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`bulan` INT(2)NOT NULL,
`tahun` INT(4)NOT NULL,
`halaman` INT(4)NOT NULL,
`issn` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`pengantar` text NOT NULL,
`redaksi` text NOT NULL,
`cover` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`created_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`created_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
`updated_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_by` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`IDJurnal`))ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

how to query in my case ?
here's my result from artikel tabel

```
IDArtikel = 1, IDJurnal=1
```

IDArtikel = 2, IDJurnal=2
IDArtikel = 3, IDJurnal=2

what i want is, 
IDArtikel = 2, IDJurnal=2
IDArtikel = 3, IDJurnal=2

IDJurnal last input

Comment: how are the two tables related with each other?

Comment: Can you show some expected sample output? What do you mean by "last of the database"? Do you want the most recently added entry?

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't know about related table. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `artikel` WHERE `IDJurnal` = (SELECT `IDJurnal` FROM `jurnal` ORDER BY `IDJurnal` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1dae/2/0

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with last of the Database?

Normaly you would do:

```
Select * From artikel Where IDArtikel >= 165166
```

Or something like that if you want to get a range of Ids you could say >= 1000 AND <= 2000 for example.

Comment: what I mean is take all artikel where IDJUrnal last input